# set file type and name of downloaded file from a asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I know there are a ton of posts concerning this exact subject, but the solutions given in them do not appear to be working for me.

Testing my web service with Postman, I get a Save As Dialog prompt but the default name is "response.txt". I would like it to be "export.csv". From my research, the following code should accomplish that but I'm still getting the default filename of "response.txt".

I can manually change the file name to export.csv and it works great, but I don't want to require users to do that if it's not necessary.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage ExportService()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var fileName = files[0].FileName;
        var content = new ByteArrayContent(files[0].FileContent);
        msg.Content = content;
        msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
        msg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "export.csv"
        };
        msg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return msg;
     }
```

Comment: This should work. I wonder if it's Postman that is causing this behavior?

Comment: @Juan I didn't even think about that. Could you recommend an alternative method to testing this post HttpPost service?

Comment: Well, it depends. How is this service being exposed? Any security? How will it be used? Does it take any parameters? There is an extension for Chrome called "Restlet Client". Try that one.